# New Sharepoint 2010 Views not Appearing as an Option in "Current View" Dropdown?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

Having created a Custom List I started to add additional views onto the List.  However, none of the new views that I create appear in the "Current View:" drop-down in the ribbon.

I have full admin rights and the views are accessible through their direct URL.

Any ideas why these views are not available in the ribbon drop-down?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to look at the menu item "Configure Views for This Location" which is in the same dropdown as the list of views?  Are those views for some reason not being shown in that page (i.e. in the "Views hidden from this location" section)?